# Unintended margin on xltabular cell

Tags: xltabular

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|X|X|}
    \caption{Proses \textit{login}} \label{tab:proses-login} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{No.}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Data Masukan}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hasil yang Diharapkan}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hasil Pengujian}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Kesimpulan}} \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    
    1  & Memasukkan \textit{email} dan \textit{password} yang benar & \textit{Login} berhasil dan menampilkan halaman \textit{dashboard} dari \textit{user} & Halaman \textit{dashboard} dari \textit{user} ditampilkan & Berhasil \\
    \hline
    2  & Memasukkan \textit{email} dan \textit{password} yang salah & Menampilkan pesan \textit{error} & \textit{Login} ditolak dan \textit{popup} berisi pesan \textit{error ditampilkan} & Berhasil \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}
```

I have unintended result where my table cell have weird left padding. How to make all the table cells are center align?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post fragments of code. Instead, edit your question to put the fragment into a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code fragment you've posted provides no information as to what's causing the indentation of the cell contents. That said, I can see no reason for centering the cell contents. I'd just let the text flow, while suppressing full justification of the cell contents.

The code does point to a serious issue, though: The table is quite a bit wider than `\textwidth`. This is happening because you're not allowing line breaks in the header cells. As I can see no reason for using the `\multicolumn` wrappers, I suggest you just get rid of them. I would also drop the **bold-facing** of the contents of the header cells.

Separately, to give the table a more open and inviting "look", I suggest you get rid of all vertical lines and use fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel} % is this right?
\hyphenation{dash-board}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suppress full justication
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \addlinespace, and \bottomrule macros

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l LLL l @{}}
    \caption{Proses \textit{login}} 
    \label{tab:proses-login} \\
    \toprule
    No. & 
    Data Masukan & 
    Hasil yang \mbox{Diharapkan} &
    Hasil Pengujian & 
    Kesimpulan \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    1  & 
    Memasukkan \textit{email} dan \textit{password} yang benar &
    \textit{Login} berhasil dan menampilkan halaman \textit{dashboard} dari \textit{user} & 
    Halaman \textit{dashboard} dari \textit{user} ditampilkan & 
    Berhasil \\
    \addlinespace
    2  & 
    Memasukkan \textit{email} dan \textit{password} yang salah &
    Menampilkan pesan \textit{error} & 
    \textit{Login} ditolak dan \textit{popup} berisi pesan \textit{error ditampilkan} & 
    Berhasil \\
    \bottomrule
    
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much